# Chromecast receiver - extremely poor framerates

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, google-cast

We are experiencing severe issues with playback fidelity on Chromecast. Using the most basic implementation of CAF or v2 on the receiver, the video serves perhaps 2 frames per seconds, showing a lot of artifacts. We are using HLS (served via Akamai). After some research, here's what we know:

- The same HLS streams play without issue on AVPlayer (iOS), EXOPlayer (Android) and Clapper (web).
- When casting the underlying mp4 file (unsegmented), the chromecast handles it beautifully.
- The issue is not with buffering itself (the playerState is not `buffering`, there is no buffering icon on the player, and the internet connection is solid)
- When forcing the chromecast to use the lowest quality video from the m3u8 manifest (240p), the player performs better (but still not perfectly).

For now, it seems to us that the HLS segments are not being processed properly (while most players handle them well). Is there anything we can do to resolve this? Our product depends on a high-quality Chromecast experience.

Comment: I think this would be better to be filed as a [bug/feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190205&template=814901).